# MATLAB Optimization Error

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

My Genetic Algorithm optimization script on Matlab runs, but at the end produces the following message: **"Optimization terminated: average change in the penalty fitness value less than options.TolFun but constraints are not satisfied."**

Why would it say that? I replaced my fitness function with one that does nothing but returns a constant number, and nothing changed. It may be the case that my constraints are not defined correctly, though I can't find the mistake. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
nGenerators = 9;
monthlyHours = 24*daysInJanuary;

(some irrelevant code here)

steamCapacities = [31.46*ones(1,2) 5.5*ones(1,3) 4*ones(1,4)];

nVars = xSize;
IntCon = 1:nVars;
LB = zeros(1, nVars);
UB = ones(1, nVars);

b = -1*steamLoad; % Ax <= b

A = zeros(monthlyHours, xSize);
for p = 1:monthlyHours
    A(p, 9*p-8:9*p) = -1*steamCapacities;
    % disp(p);
end

(some more code here)

anonFitness = @(x)mosb_test(x, fitnessData);

gaOptions = gaoptimset('Vectorized', 'off', 'UseParallel', 'always', ...
'Display', 'diagnose', 'PlotFcn', @gaplotbestf, 'Generations', 300, ...
'TolFun', 1e-15, 'StallGenLimit', 200);

[x, fval, exitFlag] = ga(anonFitness, nVars, A, b,[],[], LB, UB, [], IntCon, gaOptions);
```

Here, x represents the on/off states for a set of 9 generators for each hour of the month. Their steam production capacities are as in the variable steamCapacities, and there is a constant steam load that has to be met at every hour. This is represented by the inequality constraint.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem!  Too bad it can't be solved deterministically.  :-(  Anyway, your `TolFun` is defined by [the mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/gaoptimset.html) as being:

> Positive scalar. The algorithm stops if the weighted average relative
>   change in the best fitness function value over StallGenLimit
>   generations is less than or equal to TolFun

and `StallGenLimit` has the same description.  It makes perfect sense that a constant will give you the same error.  It appears to me that the GA is unable to converge to a solution in the `StallGenLimit`, here 200, generations.  You could try making the `TolFun` more restrictive, like 1e-12, or try and develop a far simpler model for the GA, one that will just allow you to find a solution.  Then build complexity on this model until it matches your real system.  Likely, it will fail at some point and you will be able to see why the problem can't be solved like too many degrees of freedom, too tight of constraints, etc.  HTH!